# Kafka Streams with lookup data on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I'm writing an application with Kafka Streams (v0.10.0.1) and would like to enrich the records I'm processing with lookup data. This data (timestamped file) is written into a HDFS directory on daily basis (or 2-3 times a day).

How can I load this in the `Kafka Streams` application and join to the actual `KStream`? 
What would be the best practice to reread the data from HDFS when a new file arrives there?

Or would it be better switching to `Kafka Connect` and write the RDBMS table content to a Kafka topic which can be consumed by all the Kafka Streams application instances?

**Update**:
As suggested **Kafka Connect** would be the way to go. Because the lookup data is updated in the RDBMS on a **daily** basis I was thinking about running Kafka Connect as a scheduled [one-off job](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/intro.html) instead of keeping the connection always open. Yes, because of semantics and the overhead of keeping a connection always open and making sure that it won't be interrupted..etc. For me having a scheduled fetch in this case looks safer.

The lookup data is not big and records may be *deleted / added / modified*. I don't know either how I can always have a full dump into a Kafka topic and truncate the previous records. Enabling log compaction and sending null values for the keys that have been deleted would probably won't work as I don't know what has been deleted in the source system. Additionally AFAIK I don't have a control when the compaction happens.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of Kafka Connect, but using it to put the data into a topic is the recommended way to process it with Kafka Streams. However, would it be bad for your case if Connect updates continuously instead of daily?
As an alternative, you can always use Processor API which allows to execute arbitrary code. However, it it much more effort to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommend approach is indeed to ingest the lookup data into Kafka, too -- for example via Kafka Connect -- as you suggested above yourself.

> But in this case how can I schedule the Connect job to run on a daily basis rather than continuously fetch from the source table which is not necessary in my case?

Perhaps you can update your question you do not want to have a continuous Kafka Connect job running?  Are you concerned about resource consumption (load on the DB), are you concerned about the semantics of the processing if it's not "daily udpates", or...?

> **Update:**
>   As suggested Kafka Connect would be the way to go. Because the lookup data is updated in the RDBMS on a daily basis I was thinking about running Kafka Connect as a scheduled one-off job instead of keeping the connection always open. Yes, because of semantics and the overhead of keeping a connection always open and making sure that it won't be interrupted..etc. For me having a scheduled fetch in this case looks safer.

Kafka Connect *is* safe, and the JDBC connector has been built for exactly the purpose of feeding DB tables into Kafka in a robust, fault-tolerant, and performant way (there are many production deployments already).  So I would suggest to not fallback to "batch update" pattern just because "it looks safer";  personally, I think triggering daily ingestions is operationally less convenient than just keeping it running for continuous (and real-time!) ingestion, and it also leads to several downsides for your actual use case (see next paragraph).

But of course, your mileage may vary -- so if you are set on updating just once a day, go for it.  But you lose a) the ability to enrich your incoming records with the very latest DB data at the point in time when the enrichment happens, and, conversely, b) you might actually enrich the incoming records with stale/old data until the next daily update completed, which most probably will lead to incorrect data that you are sending downstream / making available to other applications for consumption.  If, for example, a customer updates her shipping address (in the DB) but you only make this information available to your stream processing app (and potentially many other apps) once per day, then an order processing app will ship packages to the wrong address until the next daily ingest will complete.

> The lookup data is not big and records may be deleted / added / modified. I don't know either how I can always have a full dump into a Kafka topic and truncate the previous records. Enabling log compaction and sending null values for the keys that have been deleted would probably won't work as I don't know what has been deleted in the source system.

The JDBC connector for Kafka Connect already handles this automatically for you: 1. it ensures that DB inserts/updates/deletes are properly reflected in a Kafka topic, and 2. Kafka's log compaction ensures that the target topic doesn't grow out of bounds.  Perhaps you may want to read up on the JDBC connector in the docs to learn which functionality you just get for free: http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/ ?